# Design a dynamic table rows with header row and onclick row event with paging

Tags: html, dynamic-tables, data-paging

I want to design a dynamic table or list similar to the picture [Dynamic Table with paging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grhaF.png)with paging options,

Please help.

Comment: Does any HTMl expert knows how to do this, IF yes, Please respond, because need it urgently.